# where to put Text change listener code?

Tags: android

I have defined a fragment within an activity. this fragment contains a `ListView` which shows some information from a database. I have also provided an `EditText` view in which the user can type something. I want to add a code which updates the List View each time the user types in the `EditText` (using `addTextChangedListener` method). My problem is I don't know where to put the code! I put the code in fragment's `onViewCreated` method but it does not work! I don't know how to access the Views if I put the code within `onCreate` method as it does not contain any view parameter (in contrast to `onViewCreated` which has such parameter). My code can be seen below. Any help is appreciated.

```
 package com.example.lenovo.apptel_book;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    //import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class my_search_fragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_search_fragment, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        my_DBhelper db = new my_DBhelper(getActivity());

        final ListView lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        ArrayList<String> arr_lst = new ArrayList<String>();

        final Cursor cr = db.db_getAllData();
        while (cr.moveToNext())
            arr_lst.add(cr.getString(1) + "  " + cr.getString(2) + "\n" + cr.getString(3));


        ArrayAdapter<String> arr_adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arr_lst
        );

        lv.setAdapter(arr_adp);

        final EditText et_name = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.et_search_name);
        final String tmp_str = et_name.getText().toString();

        et_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {
                ArrayList<String> tmp_arr_lst = new ArrayList<String>();

                while (cr.moveToNext())
                {
                    if(cr.getString(1).contains(tmp_str))
                        tmp_arr_lst.add(cr.getString(1) + "  " + cr.getString(2) + "\n" + cr.getString(3));
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> tmp_arr_adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tmp_arr_lst
                );

                lv.setAdapter(tmp_arr_adp);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it should be no problem if you put the Listener Code in the onCreate method, try put a Toast Message inside the listener to see if the Listener working or not.

Else, the problem lying on your Listener Code which you code was incorrect. Please Edit your question and show some Code, so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

In your OnTextChanged use this code

```
  ArrayList<String> tmp_arr_lst = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (cr.moveToNext())
        {
            if(cr.getString(1).contains(s.toString())
                tmp_arr_lst.add(cr.getString(1) + "  " + cr.getString(2) + "\n" + cr.getString(3));
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> tmp_arr_adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tmp_arr_lst
        );

        lv.setAdapter(tmp_arr_adp);
```

I just changed `tmp_str` into `s.toString()`